# Are there more reliable alternatives to GKSession which allow P2P between more than 3 devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, bonjour, gksession

Some people pointed out that Bonjour is more reliable. Bonjour only is WiFi and does not support Bluetooth, no?

There must be an alternative to `GKSession` which just combines all the good things of Bonjour and Bluetooth in one simple to use API but I can't find it.

I need to automatically connect up to 8 devices for a game where players can join anytime, and `GKSession` seems to have a total limit of 3 for PeerToPeer.

Answer (score 1):

GKSession will allow for up to 16 devices as of iOS 6, I believe.  It should certainly work with at least 8, being that Bluetooth supports 8 devices.

I have successfully connected 6 devices without issue.

Comment: Well, I shouldn't say no issue... The bandwidth and latency go nuts after 3 or so devices.

Comment: So: Anki Drive is doing this currently with Bluetooth Low Energy via CoreBluetooth. Checkout my example code at https://github.com/pauley-unsaturated/Bleatr

Answer (score 1):

Updating for iOS 7, since `GKSession` is now deprecated.

The Multipeer Connectivity framework's `MCSession` class can connect up to 8 peers (current value of `kMCSessionMaximumNumberOfPeers`).

For anyone interested, I created [MCSessionP2P](https://github.com/shrtlist/MCSessionP2P.git), a demo app that illustrates the ad-hoc networking features of `MCSession`. The app advertises itself via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth and programmatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.

Comment: Hi Marco. I got a question. The MCSessionP2P keeps disconnecting the session in background. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Legolas check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138622/can-i-have-a-multipeer-connectivity-session-run-in-the-background

Comment: It will stop advertising/browsing in background but It is possible to hold the session in background. It should still be connected.